# how add padding in item of BottomNavigationView

Tags: android

I'm trying increase spacing between icon and text, but in menu item doesn't work any padding.

[image]

Tried increase height `android:layout_height="100dp"` in `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` doesn't work.

in `menu` `item` `android:padding="12dp"` doesn't work.

How can i fix this?

activity_main.xml

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/popCategoryContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:theme="@style/ActionModeStyle"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navbar_selection"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navbar_selection"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

bottom_nav_menu.xml

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:iconTintMode="screen"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_catalog"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_catalog"
        android:title="@string/title_catalog" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_basket"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
        android:title="@string/title_basket" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_favorites"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_selector"
        android:title="@string/title_favorites" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="@string/profile" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to set:

```
app:itemPaddingTop="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property on the BottomNavigationView

```
app:itemIconPadding="30dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change padding on the BottomNavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    app:itemPaddingTop="5dp"
    app:itemPaddingBottom="5dp"
    />
```